# No air coming from footwell vents. VW Passat

Tags: vw, ac, hvac, passat, vents

I'm facing a problem where no matter what button I press I can't get any air to go to the floor vents.

Whenever I press the according button air starts coming from the middle vents that's above the navigation system, if that wasn't already on (if it was then nothing happens). So far I've tried resetting the flaps by pressing the ECON and middle air vent button which did solve one of my problems of not being able to stop the air from coming through the middle vents (that is electronically, not manually with the little dial next to each vent).

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

I've also been looking for the full Component Locations manual (basically any manual that I can get any useful information out of), with no luck unfortunately, to maybe get an answer for my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely you have a blend door motor which is either stuck or quit working.

Comment: That's what the problem was, somehow it got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working again!

I removed the glovebox and the wheel connected to the motor on the other side became visible, giving it a little push while pressing the according button on the control panel got it working again.

If you're experiencing such problems a symptom of the flap being stuck is the phenomenon I described in the second paragraph in my question.

Comment: Which side is "the other side" ? The same side of the center stack as the glovebox, or the side opposite the glove box?

Comment: The side opposite to the glovebox, that's where the motor is but it's really hard to get to.